# Programmatically create virtual directory on IIS for custom web appllication project template vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, wizard, vs-extensibility

I am working on multi project custom solution structure in VS2010. One of the projects is web application. I have a `Wizard` class inheriting from interface `IWizard`. In the UI form, users will enter the name for each project in the solution template.

When I load the multi project template, is it possible to create a virtual directory on IIS for a web application created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good example of how to use Microsoft.Web.Administration for these purposes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx